# How to know when a BigQuery job insert is complete

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery.Jobs.insert to upload a csv blob to a BigQuery table (from a Google Sheets spreadsheet if that matters), but I need to know when the upload is complete so that I can run a query to process it.  Here's the code I have...

```
  csv_blob = Utilities.newBlob(csv,"application/octet-stream");
  
  //Copy the csv to BigQuery
  job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, csv_blob );

  var jobId=job.jobReference.jobId;

  //Give it a half second to complete
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);

  //see if it needs longer
  var jobstatus = job.status;
  while(jobstatus.state!="COMPLETE") {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    jobstatus = job.status;
  }
```

The upload is working, but the job.status.state never changes from "RUNNING", no matter how long I wait.  Even after I manually verify the uploaded table on the server, the job.status.state is still "RUNNING".  What is the right way to know when the job is complete?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the current status of the job with `BigQuery.Jobs.Get` ([REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get)), it appears that you're just rechecking the response you received from the initial job insertion.

An quick and dirty example of invoking this:

```
function myFunction() {
  projectID = "my-project-id"
  jobID = "some-job-id"
  location = "us-central1"

  job = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectID, jobID, {location: location});
  console.log("result state: " + job.status.state + " end time:" + job.statistics.endTime);
}
```

Comment: So I tried that:
    var jobId=job.jobReference.jobId;
    var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId,jobId);
using the same projectId that I inserted the job with, but I get the error "API call to bigquery.jobs.get failed with error: Not found"
If I look up the job in the BigQuery UI, the jobId I'm getting back from the job.jobReference.jobId call is correct.
If I try the API call on its own at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get, passing in the projictId, jobId, and location (us-west3), It finds the job and returns it.
Any ideas why my call is failing?

Comment: Augmented my answer with an example.  Also, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined for more background.

Comment: Thank you for your example. It works perfectly and resolves my issue!